# Database design

Tags: mysql, database

I am involved in project, which have thousand of the users, we need to store user's basic information, like name, job, address etc, and then we have reviews about those users. Now my question is, do in need to creates a new table for each user's review or a single table, where i stores all the reviews of all the user?
We also need to provides the search feature, so that if you wants to find a particular user, you can search it.
I am using mySql for database.

Any type of suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://databaseanswers.org/tutorial4_getting_started_with_db_design/index.htm Have a look.

Comment: Use a separate table. You can add the userid, date of review, who reviewed and the review itself. Much more flexible in the long term and you will have a history of users reviews

Comment: I would be wary of involving myself in a project of such ambition with so little knowledge. Doomed.

Comment: People have done many things with very little knowledge, the process of learning is a continue process, so one should not be afraid of asking and learning.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a table called [tbl_user] with primary key [userID], this table contains each user's basic information.

### Create a table called [tbl_review] with primary key [reviewID], this table contains every review, and has field [userID] with a one-to-one join relationship back to [tbl_user].

Appended:
You need a grand total of two tables, no more, no less, as I said.
A user is 1 person, and the number of records in [tbl_user] equals the number of unique people in your population.
Regardless whether 1 person writes 0 reviews, writes 1 review, or writes 100 reviews, he/she is represented by 1 record in [tbl_user].
A review is 1 narration written by 1 person against 1 other person, and the total number of records in [tbl_review] equals the number of reviews written.
Each record in [tbl_review] really needs 2 fields linked back to [tbl_user][userID], namely [tbl_review]![reviewer_userID] and [tbl_review]![reviewee_userID].
Regardless whether 5 reviews were written by the same person, or against the same 1 person, each individual review is represented by 1 record in [tbl_review].
This kind of topic is often called Database Project Architecture. This is the brainstorming phase, where you layout a good overall design of your database tables and relationships.

### These kinds of things can get very complicated as more datasets enter the mix.

Comment: Each user can also have multiple reviews?, so what will happens in that case?, do i need to creates a separate table for each user? I think that is not practical , because we have thousands of user.

Comment: @AbdurRahmanWarriach, no need to create separate table for each user.....< tbl_review > [ Explained above ] may have multiple reviews < reviewIDs > for one user, The above explained design is a correct approach, for me atleast !

Comment: Thanks. that means we have a [tbl_review], where we can stores each user's multiple reviews, and then link them with [tbl_user] with <reviewId>.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Actually the database design should be done considering your Application.
ie if your Application's purpose is to just digitalize all those data, and if they wont be accessed frequently, you may consider storing them in one single table.

But if you need frequent access to data and lots of search-sort operations are to be carried better split the tables,or MySQL will take a long to process the data.